# Yii2: Is there an easy way to load an existing ActiveForm with values from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, yii2, active-form

I have an existing Yii2 ActiveForm (like the one below) on a Single-Page-App where I want to load new values into it via AJAX. Is there already a simple way to do that, or do I need to make my own Javascript function to do that?

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="Conversation[cv_timestamp]">
    <input type="text" name="Conversation[cv_type]">
    <input type="text" name="Contact[ct_firstname]">
    <input type="text" name="Contact[ct_lastname]">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making my own Javascript function. Improvements are welcome.

```
 // Load ActiveForm with new model attributes via Javascript
 //
 // Form fields must have been named like this: <input name="Contact[firstname]"> <input name="Contact[lastname]">
 //
 // @param {(string|jQuery object)} formSelector - String with selector or a jQuery object
 // @param {object} models : Object where keys match the 1st level form field names and the values are the model attributes that match the 2nd level, eg.: {Contact: {firstname: 'John', lastname: 'Doe'}, }

function loadActiveForm(formSelector, models) {
    if (!(formSelector instanceof jQuery)) {
        formSelector = $(formSelector);
    }

    $.each(models, function(modelName, model) {
        $.each(model, function(attributeName, attributeValue) {
            $input = formSelector.find(':input[name="'+ modelName +'['+ attributeName +']"]');
            if ($input.length > 1) {
                if ($input.first().is(':radio')) {
                    $input.each(function() {
                        if ($(this).val() == attributeValue) {
                            $(this).prop('checked', true).click();
                            if ($(this).closest('.btn').length > 0) {
                                $(this).closest('.btn').button('toggle');
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    alert('In loadActiveForm an input had multiple tags but they are not radio buttons.');
                }
            } else {
                $input.val(attributeValue);
            }
        })
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand you correctly, you want your controllers to save your model data via ajax?

If that's the case, you should take a look at [ActiveControllers](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-rest-activecontroller).

Basically, you will have:

- index: list of models
- view: return the details of a model
- create: create a new model
- update: update an existing model
- delete: delete an existing model
- options: return the allowed HTTP methods

exposed via different verbs to use them as an API.

Comment: No, I want **load** model data into the form via ajax.

Comment: From what I understand ActiveControllers only deal with getting the data from the backend to the frontend, ie. the RESTful webservices themselves. What I need is to populate a form.

Comment: In your case, you should call the view of you activecontroller and then populate the form with the response via js. I have done that with vue (any other library/framework/whatever should work).